# IIS URL Rewrite to another site using a specific Windows identity

Tags: iis, windows-authentication, url-rewrite-module

Is it possible to use IIS' URL rewrite module in the following scenario:

Site A hosted on IIS with anonymous authentication and URL Rewrite module

Site B hosted on IIS with Windows authentication

When a client requests Site A, the request is forwarded to Site B **using a specific Windows identity**

I've tried to configure the pool associated to Site A so that it runs under the identity I want Site B to be accessed with but it does not work, i.e. the client's Windows identity is used instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL Rewrite runs so early in the stack that it doesn't have access to authentication data.so the only way to resolve the issue You can use the custom HTTP module which sends the authenticated user custom header. You could add an HTTP module to your app, or use global.asax, or you can use [www.isapirewrite.com](http://www.isapirewrite.com) which runs later in the stack and has a handle on the auth data.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/benjaminperkins/configure-application-request-routing-with-windows-authentication-kerberos

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/asiatech/a-quick-solution-when-windows-authentication-is-required-on-backend-web-server-for-arr-scenario